# Горутины и Сообщения ВК [Бот]

Tags: vkontakte-api, golang, вконтакте, бот

Как использовать Горутины, когда в секунду приходит 500+ сообщений?
Использую библиотеку: https://github.com/SevereCloud/vksdk

Comment: зависит от времени жизни ваших горутин. чем больше памяти на тачке, тем больше горутин можете создать. с чем  конкретно вы столкнулись?

Comment: мне нужен пример кода, в котором была бы распределена нагрузка на Горутины.

Comment: мне нужен пример кода, в котором была бы распределена нагрузка на Горутины.

Comment: мне нужен пример кода, в котором была бы распределена нагрузка на Горутины.